# Bad MathJax rendering

Tags: support, mathjax

Since I'm using a custom minimum font size (due to a rather high resolution display) in my browser (FF 10), math doesn't render properly for me. I'm not sure whether this is a new problem or has always been like this,. Here's what it looks like:

> [image]

Is this a somehow known issue of MathJax (... talk about bad script design), was something changed in the way it's incorporated in SE, or is there something wrong with my client? Is there a simple fix around?

(If I disable the minimum font size, math renders fine.)

Comment: Which post is that an image of?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Around the end of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2467/103

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use magnification rather than minimum font size?  I also need larger-than-default fonts and this is my solution.  Here is a screen capture showing what I see:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/yNfoP.png

Comment: By the way I use MathML rendering; which setting do you use?

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment, so again: Yesterday (?) we've been upgraded to MathJax 2.0, is that when the problem appeared?  Possibly related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/square-root-top-does-not-display

Comment: @Mr.Wizard MathML rendering on Firefox is not fully supported in MathJax 2.0 anymore.

Comment: Also see this post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/mathjax-2-0-experimental-features  They started testing MathJax 2.0 on Math.SE even before the final version came out.  There's a thread for 2.0-specific problems.

Comment: Can you describe in detail how to set a minimum font size?  When using the setting I found, I can't reproduce the problem (but the fonts don't get magnified either).  I used Content -> Font & Colours -> Advanced -> Western -> Minimum size -> 24.

Comment: @Szabolcs Same procedure here. My fonts dialog: http://i.imgur.com/AF1AR.png (I can switch the renderer to SVG or MathML, but both implementations are quite ugly, with SVG very bold and MathML only being partially supported.)

Comment: I wonder why that setting doesn't make fonts bigger here.